# Do all 3rd inversion diminished and half diminished 7th chords resolve to 64 chords?

Tags: voice-leading

I am playing around with the use of b7 as melody note in a major key and with ^2 in the bass I am able to build a diminished 42 chord (in C that is DEGBb) and I am trying to figure out how to resolve this chord. Would it be a secondary dominant type chord that resolves to a 64 chord? 64 chords sound rather dissonant themselves so how does that work?

Comment: How about: D-E-G-Bb -> C#-E-G-Bb -> D-C#-E-F#-G#-A.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to resolve it without leaving C as the tonic... I dont mind tonicizing F though but cant see how to resolve it to F in root position

Comment: Weird, I tend to use b7 in the melody in major keys in pretty much V7/IV, I7, and bVII only.

Comment: Also important - D-E-G-Bb is a **half-diminished** 4/2 chord, not a diminished 4/2 chord.

Comment: Dekka, yes that is correct, but if I am not mistaken, both would resolve to a 64 chord

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to tell out of context, but that particular chord looks like it really wants to find an F major chord to resolve to!

In the key of F, this chord is the vii diminished.  It's a common substitute for the dominant, V (a C major or C7 chord).  There is no harm in using it, but at some point you'll have to get back to C major.

In the key of C it would work like a secondary dominant,  the vii of IV.

Resolving to a IV in second inversion does seem reasonable,  but I don't recall seeing it used this way in the literature.   And that 64 chord will have a strong tendency to feel cadential so you will have a lot of work to do to bring us back to C major.  It could be a useful tool for modulating, though.

Comment: Thanks, I actually dont mind modulating to F but I cant resolve that chord to an F in root position can I?

Comment: Well, you CAN do whatever you feel like.  You're in charge.  Depending on who plays this music, they may squawk about it.  Singers may struggle to perform it when certain notes don't go the way they expect.  The music-composition-gods may shun you.  Or, you might be writing in a more pop style and love the sound of it and it could just go exactly like you want it to.

Comment: The D-E-G-Bb in the question isn't a diminished 7th chord, it's a half-diminished 7th chord. Half-diminished 7th chords aren't common substitutes for the dominant at all.

Comment: Oooooh good point!

Comment: Dekka, Half diminished 7th chords have a tritone, why cant they substitute for a dominant chord?

Comment: @armani - Huh, I guess my music theory textbooks and courses must have given me the impression that vii half-diminished 7th was *really* rare at best and basically supplanted by vii fully-diminished 7th chords, even in major keys.

Comment: @Dekkadeci as far as I know it has several uses.  Most commonly as a ii (predominant) especially in jazz where it appears both in major and minor; sometimes as a dominant; and in late romantic works it was exploited for its expressive colors.

Answer (score 2):

Your question set up is confusing.

As soon as you start with "all" in the question, the answer is simply "NO."

But why combine both diminished seventh chords and half diminished seventh chords in the question, when detail only the latter?

If you want the lowered seventh degree in major, while maintaining the major key tonic, you will get the mixolydian mode. But then you say tonicizing the `IV` chord is OK too. Not knowing if the tonality is supposed to be modal or tonal matters.

You can do all the things you laid out...

- lower the seventh degree
- maintain `C` as the tonic
- use `^2` in the bass
- use a `4/2` half diminished chord rooted on `^3`

...with something like this...

[image]

...which will maintain basic part writing principles, but it will sound modal or Impressionistic.

If you want to handle the chord as `viiø7` or `iiø7`, that's fine, but you will displace the tonic of `C` even if temporarily. The former will be a dominant and the later will be a subdominant.

So, the basic answer to the question is "no," it doesn't need to resolve to a `6/4` chord. But the choices have implications for the harmonic style and tonic.

Answer (score 1):

'All'?   No, of course not!

Having got that out of the way:

There's a tritone in there; E - B♭ (A♯), which can resolve the usual two ways, inwards to F - A  or outwards to D♯ - B.  So here's a couple of possibilities (with some implied bass notes). I'll leave it to you to give them functional labels!

[image]